# Dealing with "saga not found" scenarios

Tags: rebus, saga

Are there any mechanisms in Rebus to deal with messages that would normally be handled by a saga but for which there is no current saga that matches the correlation property? Out of the box, I believe those messages are just consumed by Rebus but there is no visibility as to what happens with them.

i.e. NServiceBus has the `IHandleSagaNotFound` to allow endpoints to deal with this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way to handle that right now. As you've probably found out, a message is simply logged that Rebus could not find an existing saga data instance for the incoming message.